# How to include only one folder and not others in Sublime's Find in Files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

In a rails project, I have several versions of view folders, based on locale. When doing global searches in Sublime 3, I'd like to have all of them excluded but one, the default locale folder. So that

`app/views/en-US`

gets searched, but any others, like

`app/views/en-UK
app/views/pt-BR`

don't. I know I can exclude everything under app/view with `-app/views/*`, but what pattern do I use to exclude everything but `app/views/en-US`?

Comment: What's wrong with just adding `app/views/en-US` as the directory to search in?

Comment: It's already searchable by default, together with all other dirs under app/views. So adding it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

After you add your project do this:

1. In the top menu bar go to Find -> Find Files In...
2. In the popup at the bottom you'll see a 'Where:' field. Click the '...' button on the right and add or exclude whichever directories you need to.

Comment: I'm really looking for a pattern to avoid manually selecting a dozen directories to exclude

Comment: Right, with this approach you can choose what to exclode or include